# In clang-format, what do the penalties do?

Tags: c++, clang-format

The [clang-format style options documentation](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html) includes a number of options called PenaltyXXX. The documentation doesn't explain how these penalties should be used. Can you describe how to use these penalty values and what effect they achieve (perhaps with an example)?

Comment: There's a video by [Daniel Jasper](http://llvm.org/devmtg/2013-04/). At around ~10:40 he provides a brief explanation of penalties. It seems to factor into deciding the "optimal" formatting.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

When you have a line that's over the line length limit, clang-format will need to insert one or more breaks *somewhere*. You can think of penalties as a way of discouraging certain line-breaking behavior. For instance, say you have:

```
Namespaces::Are::Pervasive::SomeReallyVerySuperDuperLongFunctionName(args);
// and the column limit is here:                                        ^
```

Clang-format will probably format to look a little strange:

```
Namespaces::Are::Pervasive::SomeReallyVerySuperDuperLongFunctionName(
    args);
```

You might decide that you're willing to violate the line length by a character or two for cases like this, so you could steer that by setting the `PenaltyExcessCharacter` to a low number and `PenaltyBreakBeforeFirstCallParameter` to a higher number.

Personally, I really dislike when the return type is on its own line, so I set `PenaltyReturnTypeOnItsOwnLine` to an absurdly large number.

An aside, this system was inherited from Latex, which allows you to specify all kinds of penalties for line-breaking, pagination, and hyphenation.

Comment: So a lower penalty means it will be chosen first? What do the penalty values actually map to? How do I know a 3 will be taken over say a 5? What does 3 and 5 mean?

Comment: @void.pointer: The numeric values cannot be interpreted on an absolute scale, they only have relative meaning. Furthermore, they're not used in a single context, but rather added up incrementally depending on the source code being formatted. I've been reading the source code, and there's hard-coded magic penalties littered all over ranging from 1 to at least 5000...

Comment: @Cameron I still am not sure _how_ they work. As far as I'm concerned I just see numbers with no purpose. At this time I'd have no idea what numbers to assign to which options. This system isn't very predictable.

Comment: The penalties seem to affect the line breaking algorithm, which attempts to choose the best path (where the best path is the one that places newlines in a line in such a way that the total penalty is minimized). There's many, many special cases everywhere, though. And a lot of the options interact, sometimes obscurely. There's definitely many corner cases that give weird results.

Answer (score 10):

> Can you describe how to use these penalty values and what effect they achieve (perhaps with an example)?

You can see an example in this Git 2.15 (Q4 2017) `clang-format` for [the Git project](https://github.com/git/git) written in C:

See [commit 42efde4](https://github.com/git/git/commit/42efde4c299141ddf1ca5b63909b94ab3875aa14) (29 Sep 2017) by [Johannes Schindelin (`dscho`)](https://github.com/dscho).
<sup>(Merged by [Johannes Schindelin -- `dscho` --](https://github.com/dscho) in [commit 42efde4](https://github.com/git/git/commit/42efde4c299141ddf1ca5b63909b94ab3875aa14), 01 Oct 2017)</sup>

You can see the old and new values here:

[image: clang]

To illustrate those values:

> ### `clang-format`: adjust line break penalties
>
> We really, really, really want to limit the columns to 80 per line: One
>   of the few consistent style comments on the Git mailing list is that the
>   lines should not have more than 80 columns/line (even if 79 columns/line
>   would make more sense, given that the code is frequently viewed as diff,
>   and diffs adding an extra character).
>
> The penalty of 5 for excess characters is way too low to guarantee that,
>   though, as pointed out by Brandon Williams.

([See this thread](https://public-inbox.org/git/20170928171657.GB153914@google.com/))

> **From the existing clang-format examples and documentation, it appears
>   that 100 is a penalty deemed appropriate for `Stuff You Really Don't Want`**, so let's assign that as the penalty for "excess characters", i.e.
>   overly long lines.
>
> While at it, adjust the penalties further: we are actually not that keen
>   on preventing new line breaks within comments or string literals, so the
>   penalty of 100 seems awfully high.
>
> Likewise, we are not all that adamant about keeping line breaks away
>   from assignment operators (a lot of Git's code breaks immediately after
>   the `=` character just to keep that 80 columns/line limit).
>
> We do frown a little bit more about functions' return types being on
>   their own line than the penalty 0 would suggest, so this was adjusted,
>   too.
>
> Finally, we do not particularly fancy breaking before the first parameter
>   in a call, but if it keeps the line shorter than 80 columns/line, that's
>   what we do, so lower the penalty for breaking before a call's first
>   parameter, but not quite as much as introducing new line breaks to
>   comments.